# Spring @Async without xml config

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, annotations, executor

> 25.5.3 The  Element
>
> To enable both @Scheduled and @Async annotations, simply include the
>   'annotation-driven' element from the task namespace in your
>   configuration.
>
> ```
> <task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
>
> <task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
>
> <task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
> ```
>
> Notice that an executor reference is provided for handling those tasks
>   that correspond to methods with the @Async annotation, and the
>   scheduler reference is provided for managing those methods annotated
>   with @Scheduled.

Is there anyway to do this without XML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible with the newly-released Spring 3.1, but not 3.0 - See [`@EnableAsync`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) and [`@EnableScheduling`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html).

Comment: Do all async tasks within the same configuration have to use the same Executor?

Comment: @DD. No.  The javadoc links describe how to customise it.

Comment: @skaffman which javadoc describes it? I don't see it in EnableAsync and I need to use multiple definitions

Answer (score 1):

For @Dejel question: (as I am not able to post comment)

It is possible to specify executor for certain task. This can be achieved by specyfing executor name as value of @Async annotation. See:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6847

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async